# Cross Compile helloworld.c to ARM (Cortex-A5)

Tags: c, linux, gcc, arm, embedded-linux

I am trying to cross compile simple helloworld.c to run on ARM (Cortex-A5)

I get the following error

```
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1' execvp: No such file or directory
```

**HW/SW**: SAMA5D31 processor, Android Linux

**Host**: Ubuntu 12.04

Makefile

```
CC=/home/userid/android4sam_v4.0/cross_compile_mentor/arm-2013.05/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
CFLAG=I.

helloworld:helloworld.o
     $(CC)-o helloworld helloworld.o -I.
```

I have compile the program on the host machine and works fine. Then I exported the cross compiler path and tried to compile

**cross compiler path is**

```
/home/userid/android4sam_v4.0/cross_compiler_mentor/arm-2013.05/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin
```

Also read a few post pointing to GCC_EXEC_PREFIX (env). When I echo $GCC_EXEC_PREFIX, I don't get anything back. If this is the cause can someone suggest how to address the issue.

Also I have read about defining -mcpu=cortex-A5. Is this necessary?

Also I did a ***locate cc1*** found the following

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.4.7/cc1
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/cc1
```

I also have looked at [Environment Variables Affecting GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html)

I also read something about "xgcc -B " I am not sure if this is relevant to addressing the issue.

Output from ***gcc -print-search-dirs***

```
install: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/
programs: =/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-    gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/
libraries: =/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
```

Also following command compiled without any issues

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o serial -static serial.c
```

**Update 12/1/2013**
The following issue was resolved by modifying the CC variable as Chris Stratton suggest

```
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1' execvp: No such file or directory
```

Comment: One would usually not invoke a cross compiler as `gcc` but rather as `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` however if this is an Android toolchain still other considerations may apply.

Comment: @Chris I exported the path "cross compiler path". I tried assigning the complete path to CC but still got the same error. I also tried compiling at command prompt giving the complete path I still get the same error.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Thanks for the hint, the initial issues was resolved

Comment: Dude you should follow this http://www.linux.com/community/blogs/127-personal/468920-cross-compiling-for-arm and it will work for you

Comment: Basically, you toolchain is broken. Please consider using openembedded or yocto.

Comment: so was it because of invoking `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc` instead of `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`?

Comment: @mangusta - basically the tool chain was broken. When compiled on host the everything worked fine. But didn't work when cross compiled for the target. So essentially tool chain had to be pointed to cross-compile tool chain. I was using Mentor's CodeSourcery. HTH

Comment: If you've found an answer, you should post it as an answer and get it confirmed.

Comment: @Mahendra - I kind of have to agree with  Ottavio. `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` is pretty much broken. You should switch to another toolchain, like ARM/Terry Guo's toolchain.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Android, you would use the toolchain provided by AOSP in the [NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html).

When using the Android NDK, you usually only need the minimum API that introduced the architecture/platform. For ARM, I believe that's `android-3`. You can use a later API, like `android-21`.

Below is from my MacBook. The NDK is r10d, and its installed in `/opt/android-ndk-r10d/`.

```sh
export PATH="/opt/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin:$PATH"

export CPP="arm-linux-androideabi-cpp"
export CC="arm-linux-androideabi-gcc"
export LD="arm-linux-androideabi-ld"
export AR="arm-linux-androideabi-ar"
export RANLIB="arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib"

export CFLAGS="-g3 -Os -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 --sysroot=/opt/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-21/arch-arm"
```

You definitely want to use `--sysroot` so the system knows which headers and libraries to use. Your other option is to cobble it together with `-I`, `-L` and `-l`.

Then:

```sh
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I. helloworld.c -o helloworld.exe
```

After that, you use `adb` to push it to a device and execute it. Something like:

```sh
$ adb push helloworld.exe /data/local/tmp
$ adb shell
$ shell@android:/ $ cd /data/local/tmp
$ shell@android:/data/local/tmp $ ./helloworld.exe
```

---

Here are some additional `CFLAGS` you should be aware of (from personal notes in a script to set up the environment):

```
# armeabi-v7a must use:
#   CXXFLAGS += -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp
# armeabi-v7a with Neon must use:
#   CXXFLAGS += -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon
# ARMv7 needs nothing special. In fact, specifying
#   CXXFLAGS += -march=armv7 will result in a compile error.
# Cortex A8 requires a bug fix:
#   LDFLAGS += --fix-cortex-a8
```

---

And related, here are the Cortex-A processor flags recommended by ARM Inc. Don't worry about the multilibs since Android takes care of that for you.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| ARM Core | Command Line Options                       | multilib |
|----------|--------------------------------------------|----------|
|Cortex-A* | [-mthumb] -march=armv7-a                   | armv7-ar |
|(No FP)   |                                            | /thumb   |
|----------|--------------------------------------------|----------|
|Cortex-A* | [-mthumb] -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp| armv7-ar |
|(Soft FP) | -mfpu=vfpv3-d16                            | /thumb   |
|          |                                            | /softfp  |
|----------|--------------------------------------------|----------|
|Cortex-A* | [-mthumb] -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard  | armv7-ar |
|(Hard FP) | -mfpu=vfpv3-d16                            | /thumb   |
|          |                                            | /fpu     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```